# Do we allow users asking a simple question and answer it immediately after?

Tags: support, questions

I got this question because I noticed some questions (e.g. [How can I get the field settings in a field preprocess hook?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208359/how-can-i-get-the-field-settings-in-field-preprocessor-function)) are really obvious to someone for answering, and the answer has been provided by the user who asked the question, in the same minute.

The quality of answer is fine because it is quite direct.

I found this blog [post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) from the Stack Overflow team. Is it valid in DA as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to ask a question for which you know the answer, on *Drupal Answers* like on _Stack Overflow, or any other Stack Exchange site, but the fact the question is self-answered doesn't mean it cannot be closed for the usual closing reasons we have. In particular, this means that self-answered questions aren't allowed to be subjective or too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)